# What is the probability that the first card drawn is an ace and fourth card drawn is a king given the condition that the third card is a queen?

Tags: probability, statistics

Im trying to practice statistics for my exam but this question is bogging my mind. I have 5 cards, 10, J, Q, K and A. I need to find the probability that the first card is A, fourth is a K with the condition that third is a Q. What is really bothering me is the probability that the first is A and fourth is K. I understand that I have to make two events, A=First card is A and fourth is K. B=Third card is a Q, and then have probability of A with condition B. But I do not know how to find A and B. Especially A.

Thanks for help

Comment: To clarify:  you are just sorting the cards?  If so, then there are $4$ candidates for the first card (as the $Q$ is chosen already) so it's an Ace with probability $\frac 14$.  Can you finish from here?

Comment: Phrased differently:  the condition just means that the $Q$ is gone.  Accordingly you have four slots and four cards, $\{10,J,K,A\}$.  Now, what is the probability that the $A,K$ go in the desired slots?

Comment: The question is precisely this " 5 cards labelled 10;J;Q;K;A are ordered randomly, all orders equally likely. What is the probability that A is the ﬁrst and K is fourth, conditioned on Q being third? "
So P(A) would be 1/4 + 1/3 and P(B)=1/5, but how do I get the intersection of A and B to calculate A with condition B?

Comment: Right.  So the probability that the first card is an Ace is $\frac 14$.  Now we have allocated two cards, namely $A,Q$.  So there are three left to choose from.  Accordingly, the probability that the fourth card is a $K$ is $\frac 13$, so the answer is $\frac 14 \times \frac 13 =\frac 1{12}$.

Comment: As an alternative argument:  there are exactly $4! = 24$ ways to arrange the four cards $\{10,J,K,A\}$ in the four open slots.  Of these, exactly two have the $A,K$ in the desired locations, namely $A,10,Q,K,J$ and $A,J,Q,K,10$.  Thus the answer is $\frac 2{24}=\frac 1 {12}$.

Comment: I understand now, thank you, but it is really difficult to come to this conclusions for me, especially under pressure during the exam. Thank you for your help again.